# How to get memcached working on Windows 7 for xampp?

Tags: windows, windows-7, memcached, xampp

I'm trying to get memcached working, but I have failed. I've read many tutorials, but to no avail. This is what I get when I try to install through `c:/xampp/memcached/memcached.exe`

```
failed to install service or service already installed
```

I'm pretty sure that this is not installed. I checked the processes and it's not on the list.

Comment: Did you run `memcached -d install` as Administrator?

Answer (score 0):

you must run command prompt as administrator.

to do this in windows you can right click on start menu then click command prompt (admin)